# How to alter shared memory for SageMaker Docker containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I have a Docker image in Elastic Container Registry (ECR). It was created via a simple Dockerfile which I have control over.

The image itself is fine, but I have a problem where the shared memory is insufficient when working inside a container in SageMaker Studio. Therefore I need to raise the shared memory of these containers.

To raise the shared memory of a container, I believe the usual method is to pass the `--shm-size` argument to the `docker run` command when starting the container. However, I do not have control over this command, as SageMaker is doing that bit for me. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-dockerfile.html) say that SageMaker is running `docker run <image> train` when starting a container.

Is it possible to work around this problem? Either via somehow providing additional arguments to the command, or specifying something when creating the Docker image (such as in the Dockerfile, deployment script to ECR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @rok (thank you!) it is not possible in this situation to pass arguments to `docker run`, although it would be if switching to ECS.

It is however possible to pass the `--shm-size` argument to `docker build` when building the image to push to ECR. This seems to have fixed the problem, albeit it does require a new Docker image to be built and pushed whenever wanting to change this parameter.

Comment: This does not work for me. I built the container with `--shm-size=48gb`. But when printing the shm size with `df -h` during the Sagemaker-Run i still get 30G.

Comment: @MichaelBoesl Interesting. If I recall it worked for me and I didn't have any problems after changing this. However, I was not using anywhere near as much as 30GB. I wonder if there is a hard limit in SageMaker? I am also not sure if this would differ between SageMaker services, as mine was specific to Studio.

Comment: Hey @OllieStanley. Thanks for clarification. That might be the reason, yes! I tested with sagemaker-sdk and started a Sagemaker-Training. Regarding to this comment, it seems that sagemaker is overwritting the `shm-size` during `docker run` command (depending on instance type):

https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/937#issuecomment-528263380

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/937) issue there is no option you can use in sagemaker at the moment. If ECS is an option for you, it does support `--shm-size` option in the task definition.